# Is there a way to skip an invalid record when unmarshalling csv records with apache camel bindy

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, numberformatexception, bindy

I have the following route

```
from("file:" + baseInputPath + "/exchangerates" + "?noop=true")
                                .idempotentConsumer(header(CAMEL_FILE_NAME),
                                                FileIdempotentRepository.fileIdempotentRepository(new File(
                                                                baseInputPath + "/tracker/exchangeratefiles.txt")))
                                .log("Processing exchange rate file: ${header.CamelFileName}").unmarshal()
                                .bindy(BindyType.Csv, ExchangeRateBindy.class).process(exchange -> {
                                        ExchangeRateBindy exchangeRateBindy = exchange.getIn()
                                                        .getBody(ExchangeRateBindy.class);
                                        if (exchangeRateBindy != null) {
                                                exchangeRateService.save(exchangeRateBindy.toExchangeRate());
                                        } else {
                                                log.error("Invalid exchange rate: {}", exchange.getIn().getBody());
                                        }
                                });
```

and the following bindy class

```
@Data
@CsvRecord(separator = "\\*", skipFirstLine = false)
public class ExchangeRateBindy {
    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String currencyId;
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String currencyName;
    @DataField(pos = 3)
    private double buyRate;
    @DataField(pos = 4)
    private double midRate;
    @DataField(pos = 5, defaultValue = "0")
    private double sellRate;

    public ExchangeRate toExchangeRate() {
        return ExchangeRate.builder().currencyId(currencyId).currencyName(currencyName).buyRate(buyRate)
                .midRate(midRate).sellRate(sellRate).build();
    }
}
```

and csv data

```
CAD*Canadian Dollar.*1.0332*1.0332*1.0332
AUD*Australian Dollars.*812.7459194*837.88239115*Test
BWP*BOTSWANA PULA*90.29159051*93.084113925*95.87663734
```

How do I allow my route to skip the second record which has an invalid last field with the value 'Test' instead of a numeric value? As it is the code just throws a NumberFormatException and does not process any of the records.

Answer (score 0):

There can be various options like:

- Implement [custom data format](https://people.apache.org/%7Edkulp/camel/custom-dataformat.html) that wraps Bindy data format and handles parting exception e.g. returning null on invalid record
- use [filter](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/filter-eip.html) or [validator](https://camel.apache.org/manual/validator.html) that validates the record before processing it e.g. using regular expression before it's unmarshalled.
  This can look like

```java
from("file:...")
   .idempotentConsumer(...)
   .log(...)
   .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
      .filter().regex("[A-Z]{3}\\*[^*]+\\*[0-9.]+\\*[0-9.]+\\*[0-9.]+") // put the valid regex here
      .unmarshal().bindy(BindyType.Csv, ExchangeRateBindy.class)
      .process(...);
```